# kOay kOay kOay!

Tags: word, knowledge, visual

**Try to make sense of what you see below and give me the answer.**

---

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The single word answer is:

> **PIGPEN**.
>
>  The [pigpen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher) cipher is a monoalphabetic cipher that uses unmarked partially drawn boxes for the letters A-I and the same boxes marked with a dot in the center for the letters J-R. That's what the sketch near the top refers to. (There are also wedges with or without a dot for the letters S to Z, but these are not used here: it's a pigpen, not a pigsty.)
>
>  The bottom row has eight pairs of overlaid triangles: In each pair, one triangle points either left or right; the other triangle points either up or down. Each of the pairs has either a single star (for the undotted letters A-I) or two stars (for the dotted letters J-R). The fifth and sixth as well as the seventh and eigth pairs share their stars. Each single or double star encodes a single letter:
>
>  **P**: bottom left dotted
>  **I**: bottom right undotted
>  **G**: bottom left undotted
>  **P**: bottom left undotted, again
>  **E**: top right bottom left, i.e. centre undotted
>  **N**: top right bottom left, i.e. centre dotted
>
>  [image: graphical sketch of the above]

But, but, ...

> ... don't we have to know what the overall answer is in order to decode the message? Well, there's a big hint in the title: kOay is [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) for Ok. (Well, either that or it's some wordplay, as the OP points out: kOay is O in Kay, so "Oink!")

Comment: Well done! Funny you found an explanation for the title which wasn't even intentional :D The intention was to interpret it as rot13(B va xnl = Bvax). Well it doesn't matter. Good solve.

Comment: Hehe, like any good truffle hog I can find hidden value with ease! Oink, oink!

Comment: (To make up for my blunder with explaining the title, [here](https://godaddyandthesquirrelmustbothdie.files.wordpress.com/2023/11/img_2045.gif)'a relevant punny comic strip I saw today ...)